Getting error while building CICD Pipeline (yaml) for ADF
I am building CI/CD Pipeline using yaml script for ADF deployment.
But my build job is failing in the 'Validate and Generate ARM Template' task. Although my 'validate' task is successfull. I have used the yaml script provided in microsoft documentation.
I was expecting it will generate the ARM Template.
i already added package.json and publish_config.json in the repo path
